# TLD Re-direct precedence in law

Tags: legal, internet

I hope to soon resurrect an old web-site of many years standing:  it has the URL xxxx-xxxx.com, and I still rent the domain name.

Now I am not anxious to continue hosting it in the USA   ---  though perfectly happy with hosting other sites there  ---  and it will be hosted in one of the Baltics on a VPN;  this has no bearing on the question, just forestalling some lines of answering.

Since .com is American owned, and this fact gives them jurisdiction over sites using .com   --  as in recently Homeland Security seizing a British advertising firm's site ---  I am thinking of running it under xxxx-xxxx.li and whilst keeping xxxx-xxxx.com redirect the .com to the new address [ just as i always rented and redirected xxxx-xxxx.org etc.. ]

My question is, if a secondary redirected URL is .com, though it redirects to .fr or .gr, can the American state still claim jurisdiction ?

I know tlds are basically scams;  but since we have states claiming a universal imperium, as much as say the old Soviet Union did, it seems best to protect the sites we control as best as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For legal question please use [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com).

But from a technical point: it does not matter if a redirect happens and where it points to. The visitor first hits the `.com` domain and whoever has control over this domain decides what happens next. And control over this domain means that the owner can make the DNS resolve the `.com` domain to an IP address controlled by the owner.

If the government or somebody else gets hold of the domain name it can make the DNS point it to an IP address controlled by the new owner and the intended redirect by the old owner will thus not happen.